# nestJS with typeorm : @Expose not work when entity nested

Tags: nested, nestjs, entity, typeorm, class-transformer

In [my project](https://github.com/HITTHEANTS/collact-node-server),
there are two entities; `Profile` and `Project`.

Entity `Project` has field "collaborators", which is array of `Profile`. -> [code](https://github.com/HITTHEANTS/collact-node-server/blob/main/src/projects/project.entity.ts#L25-L28)

Entity `Profile` has two `@Expose` fields, "nickname" and "id", which is well-shown when I call GET Profile API.
-> [code](https://github.com/HITTHEANTS/collact-node-server/blob/main/src/profiles/profile.entity.ts#L50-L60)
-> see result of [dev.collact.io/api/profiles/8](http://dev.collact.io/api/profiles/8).

```
{
    "createdDt": "2021-10-05T14:51:29.312Z",
    "updatedDt": "2021-10-05T14:51:29.312Z",
    "deletedDt": null,
    "photo": "https://collact-dev.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/profiles/oj2UBVFXCTnZ9z9mmy8UtU-59FD9F11-1812-4758-85B7-4347A4CE0FEF.png",
    "contact": null,
    "intro": null,
    "detail": null,
    "email": null,
    "phone": null,
    "projects": [],
    "nickname": "Tester",
    "id": 8
}
```

However, when I call GET Project API, the exposed fields, "nickname" and "id" does not come up inside "collaborators".
-> see result of [dev.collact.io/api/projects/72](http://dev.collact.io/api/projects/72).

```
{
    "createdDt": "2021-12-20T18:14:22.277Z",
    "updatedDt": "2021-12-20T18:14:22.277Z",
    "deletedDt": null,
    "id": 72,
    "photos": [
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-12-20T18:14:22.321Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-12-20T18:14:22.321Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "id": 26,
            "photo": "https://collact-dev.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/projects/cWk3fQEoperPxAS6T1QV5K.png"
        }
    ],
    "collaborators": [
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-10-03T14:53:20.165Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-12-09T13:26:11.870Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "photo": "https://collact-dev.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/profiles/oj2UBVFXCTnZ9z9mmy8UtU-59FD9F11-1812-4758-85B7-4347A4CE0FEF.png",
            "contact": "ㅆZz",
            "intro": "Zz",
            "detail": "Asdfasdf",
            "email": null,
            "phone": null
        }
    ],
    "areas": [
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-07-12T13:28:12.063Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-07-12T13:28:12.063Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "id": 1,
            "area": "drawing"
        },
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-07-12T13:28:12.063Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-07-12T13:28:12.063Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "id": 2,
            "area": "design"
        }
    ],
    "title": "title",
    "detail": ""
}
```

I already tried 2 solutions but does not work as I want.

First, I tried to add @Type(() => Profile) to "collaborators" in `Project` entity but had no difference.

Second, I thought join only worked until `collaborators`, so needed to join until `collaborators.user` like below.

```
  findOne(id: string): Promise<Project> {
    return this.projectsRepository.findOne(id, {
      relations: ['collaborators', 'collaborators.user', 'areas', 'photos'],
    });
  }
```

However, this time, "nickname" and "id" does not come up for collaborators. Rather, nested user object as a whole, comes up.

```
{
    "createdDt": "2021-10-03T11:49:51.052Z",
    "updatedDt": "2021-10-03T11:49:51.052Z",
    "deletedDt": null,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "title2",
    "detail": "",
    "collaborators": [
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-10-03T11:46:20.347Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-10-03T11:46:20.347Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "photo": null,
            "contact": null,
            "intro": null,
            "detail": null,
            "email": null,
            "phone": null,
            "user": {
                "createdDt": "2021-10-03T11:46:20.347Z",
                "updatedDt": "2021-10-03T11:46:20.347Z",
                "deletedDt": null,
                "id": 1,
                "nickname": "string1",
                "isSuperuser": false,
                "isStaff": false,
                "isActive": true,
                "loginPlatform": "manual",
                "uid": "string",
                "token": "string",
                "lastLoginDt": "2021-10-03T11:46:20.347Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "areas": [
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-10-03T11:44:05.962Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-10-03T11:44:05.962Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "id": 1,
            "area": "drawing"
        },
        {
            "createdDt": "2021-10-03T11:44:05.962Z",
            "updatedDt": "2021-10-03T11:44:05.962Z",
            "deletedDt": null,
            "id": 2,
            "area": "design"
        }
    ],
    "photos": []
}
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

adding `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)` to the controller was the key.

Also, the second solution I mentioned above (join) should be preceded.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).